# Trying to compute a specific sum equation without using for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, sum

I have a vector **x** = [x_1 x_2 ... x_n], a vector **y** = [y_1 y_2 y_3] and a matrix **X** = [x_11 x_12 ... x_1n; x_21 x_22 ... x_2n; x_31 x_32 ... x_3n].

For `i = 1, 2, ..., n`, I want to compute the following `sum` in MATLAB:

```
sum((x(i) - y*X(:,i))^2)
```

What I have tried to write is the following MATLAB code:

```
vv = (x(1) - y*X(:,1))^2; % as an initialization for i=1
for i = 2 : n
vv = vv + (x(i) - y * X(:,i))^2
end
```

But I am wondering if I can compute that without for loop in order to potentially reduce the computational time especially if `n` is very high... So are there any other much more optimal possibilities to do that in MATLAB?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: You still have to visit every element in the array.  That cannot change.  You can parallelize it, because the stream can be divided into separate chunks, but there's a limit to that benefit.  You can't do better than one thread per available core.  That might be a high number if you're using GPUs, but it's still limited.

Comment: Your loop is different from your formula. Do you want to sum the square of each difference, or square the overall sum?

Comment: No the square of each difference :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the loop at all,

```
 for i = 2:n
  y*X(:,i)
 end
```

is the same as just `y*X`, so x(i) - y*X(:,i) is simply x - y*X so basically, its:

```
vv = sum((x - y * X).^2);
```

Thanks for @beaker for pointing the mistake.

Comment: I don't think you need `cumsum` at all, just `sum(x - y*X)^2`

Comment: (or `(sum(x - y*X))^2` depending on what the OP actually wants)

Comment: `vv` looks like an accumulator to me. It should end up as a scalar, not a vector.

Comment: Thank you @GameOfThrows for your answer. So I think you also have to replace for i = 2:n by for i=1:n ??

Comment: What he's saying is you don't need the loop at all. However your loop could also have been rewritten as `v = 0; for i = 1 : n;` etc ...

Comment: (oh sorry, you mean in his answer. yes, that's correct)

Comment: Thanks also @beaker for your suggestions! :)